# redirect specific subdomain for many domains to single domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We are trying to redirect many domains but a specific subdomain to a single domain, all the domains doc root are within one folder so using the .htaccess in that root folder should be recursive for all domains, example

```
/home/user/public_html/.htaccess

/home/user/public_html/domain1/
/home/user/public_html/domain2/
/home/user/public_html/domain3/
```

We want to redirect mail.* to https://server.domain.com:2096/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mail(.*)$ https://server.domain.com:2096/ [R=301]
```

Assuming it needs to be more complex but unable to find anything similar when using a wildcard for the domain itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}` to match domain names:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mail [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://server.domain.com:2096%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, dumb question, would there need to be a vhost in Apache config for the subdomans for this to work?

Comment: Yes that's right, you can use wildcard in vhost as well.